# How to compute the t-statistic for only one cumulative abnormal return (event study)?

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, t-test, standard-deviation

I am computing the t-statistic for different values of cumulative abnormal returns $CAR_{T}$ during the event period,  for (T=-5,....,0,...,5) .

The formula I use is the following:

$t_{T}=\frac{CAR_{T}}{sqrt(var[CAR_{T}])*sqrt(\frac{L-2}{L-4})}$

which is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1. Also, L is the length of the estimation period.

Where the $var[CAR_{T}]$ is defined as:

$var[CAR_{T}]=var[\sum_{t=-5}^{T}AR_{t}]=(T+6)\sigma^2/n$

And where the abnormal returns are independent and identically distributed with an expected value of 0 and a variance of $\sigma^{2}$. n is the number of events.

**The question is, how do I get the variance when T=-5, which consists of only one abnormal return?**

Applying the variance formula, in theory, it should be:

$var[CAR_{T}]=var[AR_{-5}]=(-5+6)\sigma^2/n=\sigma^2/n$

However, what is this $\sigma^2/n$ in my data when I have only one cumulative abnormal return?

Thanks in advance!